# Using Excel pivot table to find count of unique applications on workstations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm pulling data for all locally installed applications from over 5000 Windows workstations and saving it to a CSV file. There are 2 columns that are created, 1st one is the Application name (column **A**) and the 2nd column is the workstation hostname (column **B**). We are trying to figure out the most common applications that are installed on the workstations to find a correlation of what a standard machine is versus others which have irregular pieces of software installed. I was hoping to use Excel pivot tables to show us data of what is possibly a standard workstation, with very common set of applications installed versus machines with additional applications that are not normal installs. The output on my CSV file looks like below. In the example below you can see that workstation host "ABC123" has Adobe, Cisco, Google Chrome, MS Office and Twitter installed. This is an example of a standard workstation. But if you scroll to bottom you will see hostname "LRT811" has 1 additional unexpected app called "Python" installed. We are trying to analyze and comb out irregularities such as Python application. So hoping to get unique counts of applications against the 5000 machines that i have pulled application installs from. Thank you for your help.

Adobe Reader     ABC123

Cisco            ABC123

Google Chrome ABC123

Microsoft Office ABC123

Twitter ABC123

Adobe Reader     XYZ344

Cisco            XYZ344

Google Chrome XYZ344

Microsoft Office XYZ344

Twitter XYZ344

Adobe Reader     LRT811

Cisco            LRT811

Google Chrome LRT811

Microsoft Office LRT811

Python LRT811

Twitter LRT811

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Make sure you have headers for both your columns (e.g. "Software" and "Workstation")

2) Insert a pivot table with the data

3) Use "Software" as ROWS and "Workstation" in VALUES (default should be a count)

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dvA2.png)

that should do it